# Want To Prevent Bvalidator to fire when View Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one Shopping Related Project and @ admin side i have one Form to add Categories in Database on that form i use Bvalitor to validate Entered Data but i have three Buttons and i want to perform validation only when Submit Button clicked not all.i also tried Cause validation Property but it not Work so please help me in same.
Thank You

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: show us what you have tried?